# CSS Advanced Div Positioning. Center & Middle

Tags: css, html, positioning, alignment

I want to position a `<div>`

- To Center with w.r.t body width
- To Middle with w.r.t body height

The div will have these properties:

- width of `div` will be 90%
- height of `div` auto, min. will be known

Comment: You may use margin(left,right) 5% to imitate the effect of centering width.

Comment: its the vertical positioning that is the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tested this in **IE8**, Firefox, Chrome. It does not work in IE7.

If you need this to work in <= IE7, I imagine the simplest solution would be to give up on pure CSS and use javascript for the vertical positioning.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k8sGT/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container"> 
    <div id="content"> 
        <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += 'i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i<br />';" /><br />
        i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i<br />
        i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i<br />
        i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i<br />
        i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i<br />
    </div> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;

 width: 100%;
 height: 100%
}

body {
 display: table
}

#container {
 width: 100%;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle
}

#content {
 background: red;
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 min-height: 150px
}
```

Comment: Everytime when I see `display: table` and consorts in CSS, I get mixed feelings and I always wonder: "Why not just use a `<table>` instead of all this mess?". How far would you go with *divitis*?

Answer (score 3):

You can center height [like this](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) (beware browser compatibility).

For centering width: you can use `position: absolute;` and `left: 50%;`, and them `margin: -num;`. In the margin, replace num with half of the width of the div.

Answer (score 1):

Set the div with this.  I believe it doesn't work in IE 7 and lower.  Terrible IE....

> margin:auto;
>   top:0;right:0;left:0;bottom:0;
>   position:absolute;

Comment: works on <img> .. images have a width and height. otherwise both options have to be added to the style to work for e.g. divs

Answer (score 0):

You may use margin(left,right) 5% to imitate the effect of centering width.

About the height centering, I don't know the way that you can do it with css alone (because of the unknown vertical size). But you may try using javascript to do that.

Here's an example: http://www.demtron.com/blog/post/2009/01/14/Centering-a-DIV-Window-with-Cross-Browser-JavaScript.aspx (you can ignore the detecting window size part).